# Android WebView fails URL.createObjectUrl()

Tags: android

We are devoloping a webapp which is embedded into a WebView-Container-App (basicly it's just an Activity with a fullscreen WebView calling `android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(<URL_TO_WEBAPP>)`).
At a certain point in the webapp's JavaScript code the function `URL.createObjectUrl` is called.
Starting from API level 19 the webapp works as expected. But running the app in API level 18 and lower the following error occurs: `E/Web Console﹕ Uncaught ReferenceError: URL is not defined at <URL_TO_JS_FILE>`. I did an extensive search on the web but it seems like nobody ever had that problem before.

We thought `window.URL` is a JavaScript standard function, so what could be the possible problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it has to be [prefixed with webkit on android 4.1,4.2,4.3](http://caniuse.com/#search=createObjectURL)

`(window.URL || window.webkitURL || window || {}).createObjectURL(blob);`